# Need to align bootstrap carousel and make its bullets working

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, carousel

I have a carousel of text that need to be aligned, also not sure how to make its bullets active.

By clicking on the demo link below you would see the bullet points are not in the middle of the page and based on size of the name and the text the distance between name and bullet get changed.

I need all of them (text,name,bullets) be in the middle of the page for any screen size.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jackmoore/gfcnqzy2/1/)

**[Updated demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jackmoore/gfcnqzy2/12/)**

```
.carousel-content {
    color: black;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}

.name {
    color: black;
    display: block;
    font-size: 20px;
    text-align: center;
}

.mytext {
    border-left: medium none;
    font-size: 24px;
    font-weight: 200;
    line-height: 1.3em;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    padding: 0 !important;
    text-align: center;
}

.bullets li {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #ccc;
    border: medium none;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: inline-block;
    float: none;
    height: 10px;
    width: 10px;
}

.bullets li:last-child {
    margin-right: 0;
}

.bullets li {
    border-radius: 1000px;
}
<div id="carousel-example" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-offset-3 col-xs-6">
            <div class="carousel-inner">
                <div class="item active">
                    <div class="carousel-content">
                        <div>
                            <h3>#1</h3>
                            <p>This is a twitter bootstrap carousel that only uses text. There are no images in the carousel slides.</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="item">
                    <div class="carousel-content">
                        <div>
                            <h3>#2</h3>
                            <p>This is another much longer item. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Animi, sint fuga temporibus nam saepe delectus expedita vitae magnam necessitatibus dolores tempore consequatur dicta cumque repellendus eligendi ducimus placeat! Sapiente, ducimus, voluptas, mollitia voluptatibus nemo explicabo sit blanditiis laborum dolore illum fuga veniam quae expedita libero accusamus quas harum ex numquam necessitatibus provident deleniti tenetur iusto officiis recusandae corporis culpa quaerat?</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="item">
                    <div class="carousel-content">
                        <div>
                            <h3>#3</h3>                            
                            <p>This is the third item.</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Controls --> <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-example" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
  </a>
 <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-example" data-slide="next">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
  </a>

</div>

        setCarouselHeight('#carousel-example');

        function setCarouselHeight(id) {
            var slideHeight = [];
            $(id + ' .item').each(function() {
                // add all slide heights to an array
                slideHeight.push($(this).height());
            });

            // find the tallest item
            max = Math.max.apply(null, slideHeight);

            // set the slide's height
            $(id + ' .carousel-content').each(function() {
                $(this).css('height', max + 'px');
            });
        }
```

**UPDATE**

I changed the code of bullets to the following and it causes them to move a bit to to the top. (in the middle of the text)

```
<div class="col-xs-offset-4 col-xs-8">
      <ol class="bullets carousel-indicators"> 
        <li class="active" data-target="#carousel-example" data-slide-to="1"></li>
        <li class="" data-target="#carousel-example" data-slide-to="2"></li>
        <li class="" data-target="#carousel-example" data-slide-to="3"></li>
        </ol>
```

Comment: Just see what i said & apply no need of css it will automatically take care.

Comment: Jack still you need to do like data-slide-to from 0 not from 1

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Just a few changes to make it all work:

**1) Zero indexing.** Start `data-slide-to` from 0, not from 1:

```
<ol class="bullets carousel-indicators"> 
    <li ... data-slide-to="0"></li>
    <li ... data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li ... data-slide-to="2"></li>
</ol>
```

**2) Slides padding.** Add some extra padding to slides for bullets:

```
.carousel-content {
    ...
    padding: 20px 0 50px 0;
}
```

**3) Bullets offset.** Reduce bottom bullets offset to look it better:

```
.bullets {
    ...
    bottom: 10px;
}
```

### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/tonystar/gfcnqzy2/16/)

[image: Demo]

Answer (score 4):

First of all. Change your bullets to this

```
    <ol class="bullets carousel-indicators"> 
      <li class="active" data-target="#carousel-example" data-slide-to="0"></li>
      <li class="" data-target="#carousel-example" data-slide-to="2"></li>
      <li class="" data-target="#carousel-example" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    </ol>
```

Javascript counts from 0

I've added some css for the bullets and de slider container. And I moved the bullets to the back of the parent div.. It seems to work

http://jsfiddle.net/gfcnqzy2/17/

Answer (score 3):

Try this rules in `.bullets` element:

```
.bullets {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Change the wrapper's offset to 2:

```
<div class="col-xs-offset-2 col-xs-8">
```

Also, reset margin and padding from `ol`:

```
ol {
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
}
```

Check the [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/gfcnqzy2/2/)

Comment: I checked out the demo the issue is now the text is on the right side and bullets are in the middle of the page. They must be all in the middle of the page. So there is text then name and in the last line bullets all in middle.

Answer (score 3):

To make the bullet working you can just give one attribute to each list item as `data-target="#myCarousexxx"`. It will automatically work no need of script to write.

Add one class to bullets list UL that `carousel-indicators`.

Your `data-slide-number` should be as `data-slide-to`

Dats it buddy. No need of css it will automatically will align. Study the bootstarp.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/gfcnqzy2/10)

Comment: I added data-target="#carousel-example"  to all bullets but it does not work. would you please distinguish your answer for each part (bullets functionality, design)

Comment: First add one class `carousel-indicators` to ol

Comment: Second you added `data-target=` gr8. Third you change `data-slide-number` to `data-slide-to` . It will work

Comment: Alright, when I add that to the ol, the bullets go up and locate in the middle of the text.

Comment: Just give some min-height:200px or something to each item. It will work...Try out some css.

Comment: So eventually need to use CSS, bootstrap wont help here :D

Comment: No you need to study that...You didn't followed the structure. You can find in bootstrap website buddy.. For slider they have good tutorial ...happy coding

Answer (score 3):

```
 <div class="col-xs-offset-4 col-xs-8">
      <ol class="bullets">
        <li class="active" data-slide-number="1"></li>
        <li class="" data-slide-number="2"></li>
        <li class="" data-slide-number="3"></li>
        </ol>
  </div>
```

Either offset your bullets, or move your content areas to span the whole width

Comment: I did it but text,name and bullets are not aligned.

Answer (score 3):

**CSS**

```
.col-xs-offset-4 {
  /* margin-left: 33.33333333%; */
}
.col-xs-8 {
  /* width: 66.66666667%; */
}
```

> The above two causes your Div to appear at the right-side

So to overcome those use the below CSS Code i have attacked some Selectors so it wont affect your bottstrap.css

```
 .row .col-xs-offset-4 {
       margin-left: 0;
    }
    .row .col-xs-8 ,.carousel-content div{
       width:100%;
    }
.carousel-content{
    text-align:center;

}


  .bullets.carousel-indicators{
      position:initial;
       padding:0;
       margin:0;
        width:100%;
}
```

> 1. The `margin` and `width` for the two classes have been modified by the above css.
> 2. The child `div` inside the `carousel-content` was not taking the full width of it parent so we use `width` property for that.
> 3. `text-align` to make the things align at the center of the `Div`
> 4. `padding` & `margin` to remove the extra default CSS to the `carousel-indicators`

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/gfcnqzy2/13/)

Comment: Thanks I used the css you offered, the bullets still need to be a bit to the left.  Also how to make the bullets change while carousel is working?

Comment: Thanks please check out the updated demo link. I made the bullets active and used your code but the bullets are now located in the middle of the text.

Comment: @Jack see now jack see the DEMO too

Comment: I tried it, the only issue is that the size of the text need to get smaller forsmall screens.

Comment: I think you should use media query for making the text size smaller for the desired screen size or devices.

Answer (score 3):

Your main problem is that your markup is a bit different than the markup required by Bootstrap for its carousel. You therefore need to change the following:

1. Your `carousel-indicators` `ol` should be nested right under the `.carousel` and not in the `carousel-inner`. This will not only solve your alignment issue for the indicators, but will also cause them to be displayed as expected (ie. the "active" indicator will be highlighted).
2. There is no need for rows and columns in the carousel since you can align everything with `text-align: center;`. In fact the `col-xs-offset-4 col-xs-8` is what causes your text to be misaligned since it takes up 8 columns but leaving 4 columns blank at the left side of the page.

The updated markup therefore becomes as follows:

```
<div id="carousel-example" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
        <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
        <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="1"></li>
        <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="2"></li>
    </ol>
    <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="item active">
            <div class="carousel-content">
                <div>
                    <p class="mytext">This is the text of the first item.</p>   <span class="name">This is the first name</span>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <div class="carousel-content">
                <div>
                    <p class="mytext">This is the text of the second item.This is the text of the second item.</p>  <span class="name">This is the second name, This is the second name</span>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <div class="carousel-content">
                <div>
                    <p class="mytext">This is the text of the third item.This is the text of the third item.This is the text of the third item.</p> <span class="name">This is the third name,This is the third name,This is the third name,</span>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

You will also notice that with this markup you will need minimal extra CSS since most of what you need to do will be taken care of by the Bootstrap CSS.

See the [updated demo](http://jsfiddle.net/qgetgnrL/1/).

As a side note, according to Bootstrap you should be using the `carousel-caption` class for any text you need to insert in the carousel (what is now in `carousel-content`), since Bootstrap assumes that your carousel will also have an image for each item. Since however this is not the case for you I have kept the `carousel-content` class instead since the `carousel-caption` is not correctly aligned/displayed without a corresponding image.

Answer (score 3):

Use custom made carousel, here is an exmpale of something i created quickly.

http://jsfiddle.net/gppg7k6n/

And some jquery:

```
var cont = $('.slides'),
    slide = cont.find('.slide'),
    nav = cont.find('.nav'),
    li = null,
    len = slide.length,
    index = slide.filter('.start').index();

for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    nav.append($('<li>'));
}

li = nav.find('li');

showSlide();
slide.stop().eq(index).show();

function updateLi() {
    li.removeClass('white');
    li.eq(index).addClass('white');
}

function showSlide() {
    slide.stop().fadeOut().eq(index).stop().fadeIn();
    updateLi();
}
cont.click(function () {
    index = ++index % len;
    showSlide();
});

nav.click(function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
});

li.click(function (e) {
    index = $(this).index();
    showSlide();
});
```